# Trying to build MonoGame content in MG Editor for MacOS M1

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, apple-m1, monogame

I am currently developing a game in C# using .NET 7.0.203 in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac (so M1). The MonoGame project uses DeskotGL and should be cross platform.

The game will be developed using MonoGame game engine. The project is currently empty. I only wanted to try to import a map and run the project to see if it works.

To be able to run the map first I need to import the .blend map inside the MonoGame Editor and build it in order to have the .xnb file that will be used in VS but I am getting that error.

Error:

[image: screenshoot]

This is my actual code in Game1.cs:

```csharp
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace LaserLounge
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
        private Model _model;

        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // Load the 3D model
            _model = Content.Load<Model>("mercedes");
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // Set up the necessary transformations and camera settings here
            Matrix world = Matrix.Identity;
            Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 5), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
            Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.1f, 100f);

            // Render the 3D model
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in _model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
                {
                    BasicEffect effect = (BasicEffect)meshPart.Effect;
                    effect.World = world;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple versions of MonoGame Content Pipeline but still had the same problem.

I think I explained my issue, if someone doesn't understand something or I missed some details let me know.